# UWP reset main frame

Tags: uwp, mvvm-light

I've got an MVVM Light UWP project where I want to reset the app and reload the UI. I was hoping that I could just call into my App class to do this, but I'm getting strange things happening.

As a test, if I call

```
Window.Current.Content = null;
```

form within a page in my app, then the content area of the window goes blank as expected. But if rerun my setup code that sets up the the AppShell (my root container page) and sets Window.Current.Content to that then nothing changes.

The ViewModel constructor doesn't get hit again so I suspect the issue has to do with how MVVM Light instantiates the ViewModel. Maybe there's something else I need to do to get a fresh instance of that?

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is that you've set `Window.Current.Content = null;`, by MVVM Light the `Window.Current.Content` is the `Frame` and usually we call this as a `rootFrame`, as you can see it from the `App.xaml.cs` code:

```cs
Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
```

Once you set it as null, then the `Frame` which is used for hosting the pages is gone, you will need to firstly create a new instance of a `Frame` just as it does in `App.xaml.cs`:

```cs
if (rootFrame == null)
{
    // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page
    rootFrame = new Frame();

    rootFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;

    if (e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
    {
        //TODO: Load state from previously suspended application
    }

    // Place the frame in the current Window
    Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
}

if (rootFrame.Content == null)
{
    // When the navigation stack isn't restored navigate to the first page,
    // configuring the new page by passing required information as a navigation
    // parameter
    rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments);
}
```

Since you didn't post any code of your "setup code that sets up the the AppShell", I'm writing an answer here just guess the possible issue with your code, and here is my demo for resetting the page:

```cs
Window.Current.Content = null;
var rootFrame = new Frame();
Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
await Task.Delay(1000);
_navigationService.NavigateTo(ViewModelLocator.SecondPageKey, "lala");
```

If there is still problem, please leave a comment or maybe share us more code.

Comment: Thanks. I was only setting the Window Content to null as a test, as I said in my question...just to prove that it was actually cleared out. I understand that it needs to be set to a frame. Your code is helpful, but can you give some detail on what _navigationService is?

Comment: It is the `private readonly INavigationService _navigationService;`, if you use MVVM Light template to create a UWP app, you can find this in `MainViewModel.cs`. The instance of this  is actually created in the `ViewModelLocator.cs`.